# Spring Integration Java DSL -- Configuration of aggregator

Tags: java, spring-integration, dsl, aggregator

I have a very simple integration flow, where a RESTful request is forwarded to two providers using a publish-subscribe channel. The result from both RESTful services is then aggregated in a single array. The sketch of the integration flow is as shown below:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow flow() throws Exception {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("inputChannel")
            .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s.applySequence(true)
                .subscribe(f -> f
                        .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://provider1.com/...")
                                .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                                .expectedResponseType(ItemDTO[].class))
                ).subscribe(f -> f
                        .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://provider2.com/...")
                                .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                                .expectedResponseType(ItemDTO[].class)
                        )
                )
            )
            .aggregate()
            .get();
}
```

However, when running my code, the resulting array contains the items returned by only one of the RESTful services. Is there any configuration step I am missing?

**UPDATE**

The following version corresponds to the full solution, taking into account Artem's comments.

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow flow() throws Exception {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("inputChannel-scatter")
            .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s.applySequence(true)
                .subscribe(f -> f
                        .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://provider1.com/...")
                                .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                                .expectedResponseType(ItemDTO[].class))
                        .channel("inputChannel-gather"))
                .subscribe(f -> f
                        .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://provider2.com/...")
                                .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                                .expectedResponseType(ItemDTO[].class))
                        .channel("inputChannel-gather")))
            .get();
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow gatherFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("inputChannel-gather")
            .aggregate(a -> a.outputProcessor(g ->  new GenericMessage<ItemDTO[]>(
                        g.getMessages().stream()
                                .flatMap(m -> Arrays.stream((ItemDTO[]) m.getPayload()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new ItemDTO[0]))))
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it doesn't work that way.

The `.aggregate()` is a **third** subscriber to that `publishSubscribeChannel`.

You have to sever your flow to two of them. Like this:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow publishSubscribeFlow() {
        return flow -> flow
                .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .subscribe(f -> f
                                .handle((p, h) -> "Hello")
                                .channel("publishSubscribeAggregateFlow.input"))
                        .subscribe(f -> f
                                .handle((p, h) -> "World!")
                                .channel("publishSubscribeAggregateFlow.input"))
                );
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow publishSubscribeAggregateFlow() {
        return flow -> flow
                .aggregate(a -> a.outputProcessor(g -> g.getMessages()
                        .stream()
                        .<String>map(m -> (String) m.getPayload())
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))))
                .channel(c -> c.queue("subscriberAggregateResult"));
    }
```

Pay attention, please, to the `.channel("publishSubscribeAggregateFlow.input")` usage from both subscribers.

To be honest that is a point of any `publish-subscribe`. We must know where to send the result of all subscribers if we are going to aggregate them.

Your use-case recalls me the [Scatter-Gather](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather) EIP pattern.

We don't have its implementation in the DSL yet. 
Feel free to raise a [GH issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues) on the matter and we will try to handle it in the upcoming `1.2` version.

**UPDATE**

The GH issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/75

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help Artem. In fact, I tried using channels and separate flow before, without success because I had also the problem with the aggregator. Your answer gave me also hints on how to write the aggregator.

Comment: Great! But Scatter-Gather would be as a good addition to the DSL. So, don't be shy to raise a GH issue anyway!